# use one common public ip address for multiple ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using aws ec2 instances as web servers.

There are more then 20 web servers and they has to connect to some external services. Those external services has ip based security rules. Because of this reason I have to use a only one or two public ip address to connect those services.

How can i route outgoing traffics to use only one public ip address ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could use a NAT instance for that. 
Just make sure your instance is large enough to accommodate the desired throughput.

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html

Comment: thanks. you mean, should i create a new instance(with elastic ip) to route traffic?

Comment: Yes, have one instance to act as a NAT and route traffic through it, as explained in the referenced documentation, so all traffic will have the same source IP. Of course, also consider if this is an acceptable usage policy of the service.

Comment: It looks like this is the only solution, but it causes a single point of failure.